# Is such Ethereum bytecode a waste of gas?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I am trying to write some solidity code. [Compiling](https://remix.ethereum.org) the code below, I get the bytecode, but there seems to be some **unnecessary instructions** in the bytecode.

**Solidity:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Coin {
    // The keyword "public" makes variables
    // accessible from other contracts
    address public minter;

    // Constructor code is only run when the contract
    // is created
    constructor() {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

**Raw ethereum bytecode:**

```
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
```

[**Decompile:**](https://ethervm.io/decompile)

```
contract Contract {
    function main() {
        memory[0x40:0x60] = 0x80;
        var var0 = msg.value;
    
        if (var0) { revert(memory[0x00:0x00]); }
    
        storage[0x00] = msg.sender | (storage[0x00] & ~0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff);
        memory[0x00:0xf7] = code[0x5f:0x0156];
        return memory[0x00:0xf7];
    }
}
```

## Waste?

I noticed this line of code.

```
storage[0x00] = msg.sender | (storage[0x00] & ~0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff);
```

I understand the purpose of these code is to store the address of the transaction sender in storage of the contract.
But can't it be written like this?

```
storage[0x00] = msg.sender;
```

It seems to save more gas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that specific case, yes, but otherwise it's absolutely necessary :

Type `address` is 20 bytes long, while a storage slot is 32 bytes long. This means that other state variable may be packed with `minter` in storage slot 0. This packing might be done from solidity where the compiler generates the layout itself, or from assembly where the developer handles it directly.

```
storage[0x00] = msg.sender | (storage[0x00] & ~0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff);
```

Simply ensures that `storage[0]` last 20 bytes are cleared and replaced with msg.sender, preserving the upper 12 bytes.

This example using the "more gas efficient" approach has side effects on the packed variable : `boolean` becomes `false` because `sstore` overwrites it with zeros.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Coin {
    
    address public minter;
    bool public boolean = true;

    constructor() {
        assembly {
            sstore(0, caller())
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler simply prioritize the correctness of the generated code rather than potentially side effect inducing optimizations, which is the right decision.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize there would still be packaging, now I understand